# How to switch back from true to false in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a dice game and need some help to switch back from player 2 to player 1. The game is about rolling how high you can and when you roll a 1 you switch to the other player. I have done so that when player 1 rolls a 1 it switches to player 2. But when player 2 rolls a 1 nothing happens.

```js
var swithcing = false;

var current1 = 0;
var total1 = 0;

var current2 = 0;
var total2 = 0;

function roll() {
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

  var player1score = document.querySelector('.player1total');
  var player1curent = document.querySelector('.player1');

  var player2score = document.querySelector('.player2total')
  var player2curent = document.querySelector('.player2')

  if (randomnumber == 1) {
    swithcing = true;
    player1curent.innerHTML = 0;
    player2curent.innerHTML = 0;
  }

  if (swithcing == true) {
    current2 += randomnumber;
    player2score.innerHTML = current2;
    player2curent.innerHTML = randomnumber;
  }

  if (swithcing == false) {
    current1 += randomnumber;

    player1score.innerHTML = current1;
    player1curent.innerHTML = randomnumber;
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Player 1</h1>
<h2 class="player1"></h2>
<h3 class="player1total">0</h3>

<h1>Player 2</h1>
<h2 class="player2"></h2>
<h3 class="player2total">0</h3>

<input type="button" onclick="roll()" value="Roll Dice!" />
<input type="button" onclick="hold()" value="Hold!" />
```

Comment: do you want to change player if rolling one? or what should happen exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Once you change `swithcing = true;`. It never goes back to `false`. Hence,
it stays at `player 2`

##### The solution:

```js
if(randomnumber == 1){

    swithcing = !swithcing; // Invert the current value 

    player1curent.innerHTML = 0;
    player2curent.innerHTML = 0;

}
```

The `!` operator known as a [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) is used to change `swithcing` to `false` if it's `true` and vice versa.